# If record exist load existing record and disable certain control

Tags: ms-access

I have a form for entering new records into database. After entering data into one of the controls I would like to check if a record with that data already exists in the database. If it does then I would like to move to that existing record and disable the control above metnioned control since value for this field should not be edited on existing records. All other fields can still be edited.

Now I was thinking of using an OnExit event but I have a hard time writing a proper macro which would check if record with that value already exists, load that existing record and disable the mentioned control.

I'm afraid I have almost no expirience writing macros in Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great news I managed to find a solution to my problem. How did I do it?

Well my first attempt of solving the "does record exist" part of the problem is to go and count all the records that met specific criteria (their field contents match the contents of the input box for that field. Now because I have very poor knowledge of VBA syntax I must shamefully admit that I spent a whole day getting that to work but I did it.

Now here comes even more shameful moment for me. Just about five minutes later when I was tackling the "move to the existing record" part of my problem I realized that I used the dumbest approach for solving my fist part.

Why is the above solution for first part of my problem the dumbest approach?
That is because I was trying to count how many times a record with unique field value exists in database. And that is dumb because if you have unique field the it means that there can either be one or none matching records in the database.

Now instead of using DCount I ended up using FindFirst instead. And the biggest advantage of using FindFirst is that it actually solves both of my problems (does the record exists and move to it if it does) at the same time.

So I ended up with this little neat code

```
Private Sub TKlasifikacijska_številka_Exit(Cancel As Integer)

    Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
    'Find existing record
    rst.FindFirst "Klasifikacijska_številka = " & "'" & [TKlasifikacijska_številka] & "'"
    'Recod found
    If Not rst.NoMatch Then
        'Undo last editing in order to avoid duplicates error after moving to existing record
        Me.Undo
        'Move to the existing record
        Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark
    'Record wasn't found
    Else
        'Don't do nothing - keep user editing new record
    End If

End Sub
```

For clarification:

- Klasifikacijska_številka is my unique field in the data table
- TKlasifikacijska_številka is my unique field edit box

Probably not the best naming pattern and will come bite me in the future. But at the moment most importantly to me is that it works.

Oh as for the last part of my problem (disabling edit control on existing records) I figured out that it is much better to use different event and that is forms OnCurrent event. That event is fired every time a record position is changed and you can easily check to see if the record is already stored in database or is still a new record using this simple code.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    'Existing record
    If Not Me.NewRecord Then
        'Disable the unique field edit box to prevent editing data of that field since 
        'such data should not be edited on existing records
        Me.TKlasifikacijska_številka.Enabled = False
        'Change header label caption to let user easily know that he is on an existing record
        Me.Oznaka16.Caption = "Obstoječi zapis"
    Else
        'Enable the unique field edit box to enable user to enter data into it
        Me.TKlasifikacijska_številka.Enabled = True
        'Change header label caption to let user easily know that he is on a new record
        Me.Oznaka16.Caption = "Nov zapis"
    End If
End Sub
```

Any way I hope this would come useful to somebody.